# PySpark - Create a pyspark dataframe using Kakfa Json message

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, apache-kafka-streams

I am using pyspark structed streaming and reading data from Kafka topic which is in Json complex format.

I am using Spark Structred Streaming Format as Kafka and code as below -

```
spark = SparkSession.builder \
        .appName("PythonSparkStreamingKafka") \
        .getOrCreate()

kafkaStreamDF = spark \
            .readStream \
            .format("kafka") \
            .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") \
            .option("subscribe", "main.test.mysql.main.test_bank_data") \
            .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") \
            .load()

kafkaStreamDF1 = kafkaStreamDF.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")

message_schema = StructType().add("payload",StringType())
kafkaStreamDF2 = kafkaStreamDF1.select(from_json(col("value"),message_schema).alias("message"))

consoleOutput = kafkaStreamDF2.writeStream \
                .outputMode("append") \
                .format("console") \
                .option("truncate", "false") \
                .start()
```

I have extracted the data from message till Payload part of kafka json message and its output on console like below -

```
|[{"before":null,"after":{"transaction_id":20,"account_no":409000611074,"transaction_date":18490,"transaction_details":"INDO GIBL Indiaforensic STL12071 ","value_date":18490,"withdrawal_amt":"AMTWoA==","deposit_amt":null,"balance_amt":"K6LiGA=="},"source":{"version":"1.4.0-SNAPSHOT","connector":"mysql","name":"main.test.mysql","ts_ms":0,"snapshot":"true","db":"main","table":"test_bank_data","server_id":0,"gtid":null,"file":"binlog.000584","pos":15484438,"row":0,"thread":null,"query":null},"op":"c","ts_ms":1611582308774,"transaction":null}]|

|[{"before":null,"after":{"transaction_id":21,"account_no":409000611074,"transaction_date":18490,"transaction_details":"INDO GIBL Indiaforensic STL13071 ","value_date":18490,"withdrawal_amt":"AV741A==","deposit_amt":null,"balance_amt":"KkPpRA=="},"source":{"version":"1.4.0-SNAPSHOT","connector":"mysql","name":"main.test.mysql","ts_ms":0,"snapshot":"true","db":"main","table":"test_bank_data","server_id":0,"gtid":null,"file":"binlog.000584","pos":15484438,"row":0,"thread":null,"query":null},"op":"c","ts_ms":1611582308774,"transaction":null}]|
```

Now I would like to extract the data of after part and read the filed data in dataframe like below -

```
transaction_id|account_no|transaction_date|transaction_details|value_date|withdrawal_amt|deposit_amt|   balance_amt

20              | 409000611074  |   16/08/2020       |  INDO GIBL Indiaforensic STL12071 |  16/08/2020  |   129000.00      |    (null)      | 7320950.00

21              | 409000611074  |   16/08/2020       |  INDO GIBL Indiaforensic STL13071 |  16/08/2020  |   230013.00      |    (null)      | 7090937.00
```

Please suggest me how to achieve this expected output in a pyspark dataframe?

Added below the exact value feild of kafka message -

{"schema":{"type":"struct","fields":[{"type":"struct","fields":[{"type":"int32","optional":false,"field":"transaction_id"},{"type":"int64","optional":false,"field":"account_no"},{"type":"int32","optional":true,"name":"io.debezium.time.Date","version":1,"field":"transaction_date"},{"type":"string","optional":true,"field":"transaction_details"},{"type":"int32","optional":true,"name":"io.debezium.time.Date","version":1,"field":"value_date"},{"type":"bytes","optional":true,"name":"org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Decimal","version":1,"parameters":{"scale":"2","connect.decimal.precision":"12"},"field":"withdrawal_amt"},{"type":"bytes","optional":true,"name":"org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Decimal","version":1,"parameters":{"scale":"2","connect.decimal.precision":"12"},"field":"deposit_amt"},{"type":"bytes","optional":true,"name":"org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Decimal","version":1,"parameters":{"scale":"2","connect.decimal.precision":"12"},"field":"balance_amt"}],"optional":true,"name":"main.test.mysql.main.test_bank_data.Value","field":"before"},{"type":"struct","fields":[{"type":"int32","optional":false,"field":"transaction_id"},{"type":"int64","optional":false,"field":"account_no"},{"type":"int32","optional":true,"name":"io.debezium.time.Date","version":1,"field":"transaction_date"},{"type":"string","optional":true,"field":"transaction_details"},{"type":"int32","optional":true,"name":"io.debezium.time.Date","version":1,"field":"value_date"},{"type":"bytes","optional":true,"name":"org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Decimal","version":1,"parameters":{"scale":"2","connect.decimal.precision":"12"},"field":"withdrawal_amt"},{"type":"bytes","optional":true,"name":"org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Decimal","version":1,"parameters":{"scale":"2","connect.decimal.precision":"12"},"field":"deposit_amt"},{"type":"bytes","optional":true,"name":"org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Decimal","version":1,"parameters":{"scale":"2","connect.decimal.precision":"12"},"field":"balance_amt"}],"optional":true,"name":"main.test.mysql.main.test_bank_data.Value","field":"after"},{"type":"struct","fields":[{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"version"},{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"connector"},{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"name"},{"type":"int64","optional":false,"field":"ts_ms"},{"type":"string","optional":true,"name":"io.debezium.data.Enum","version":1,"parameters":{"allowed":"true,last,false"},"default":"false","field":"snapshot"},{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"db"},{"type":"string","optional":true,"field":"table"},{"type":"int64","optional":false,"field":"server_id"},{"type":"string","optional":true,"field":"gtid"},{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"file"},{"type":"int64","optional":false,"field":"pos"},{"type":"int32","optional":false,"field":"row"},{"type":"int64","optional":true,"field":"thread"},{"type":"string","optional":true,"field":"query"}],"optional":false,"name":"io.debezium.connector.mysql.Source","field":"source"},{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"op"},{"type":"int64","optional":true,"field":"ts_ms"},{"type":"struct","fields":[{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"id"},{"type":"int64","optional":false,"field":"total_order"},{"type":"int64","optional":false,"field":"data_collection_order"}],"optional":true,"field":"transaction"}],"optional":false,"name":"main.test.mysql.main.test_bank_data.Envelope"},"payload":{"before":null,"after":{"transaction_id":146,"account_no":409000611076,"transaction_date":18652,"transaction_details":"TRF FROM  Indiaforensic SERVICES","value_date":18652,"withdrawal_amt":"AA==","deposit_amt":"B6Eg","balance_amt":"B6Eg"},"source":{"version":"1.4.0-SNAPSHOT","connector":"mysql","name":"main.test.mysql","ts_ms":1611587463000,"snapshot":"false","db":"main","table":"test_bank_data","server_id":19105,"gtid":null,"file":"binlog.000584","pos":46195052,"row":0,"thread":1604558,"query":null},"op":"c","ts_ms":1611587463181,"transaction":null}}

From here have i have converted into string on DF1 and taken the part of Payload into DF2.

**-- Final working condition comments --
Added after transform the SMT in Debezium MySQL connector in Kafka connect side I am getting the message value in PySpark structred streaming with Kafaka as below -**

```
Value = 
{"transaction_id":21,"account_no":409000611074,"transaction_date":"2020-08- 
229","transaction_details":"INDO GIBL Indiaforensic STL13071 
","value_date":"2020-08-22","withdrawal_amt":"230013.00","deposit_amt":null,"balance_amt":"7090937.00"}

message_schema = StructType([
StructField('transaction_id', IntegerType(), True),
StructField('account_no', LongType(), True),
StructField('transaction_date', StringType(), True),
StructField('transaction_details', StringType(), True),
StructField('value_date', StringType(), True),
StructField('withdrawal_amt', StringType(), True),
StructField('deposit_amt', StringType(), True),
StructField('balance_amt', StringType(), True)   
]
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the schema of the string JSON messages to the `from_json` function.

Having your messages like this:

```
#+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
#|value                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           |
#+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
#|[{"before":null,"after":{"transaction_id":20,"account_no":409000611074,"transaction_date":18490,"transaction_details":"INDO GIBL Indiaforensic STL12071 ","value_date":18490,"withdrawal_amt":"AMTWoA==","deposit_amt":null,"balance_amt":"K6LiGA=="},"source":{"version":"1.4.0-SNAPSHOT","connector":"mysql","name":"main.test.mysql","ts_ms":0,"snapshot":"true","db":"main","table":"test_bank_data","server_id":0,"gtid":null,"file":"binlog.000584","pos":15484438,"row":0,"thread":null,"query":null},"op":"c","ts_ms":1611582308774,"transaction":null}]|
#|[{"before":null,"after":{"transaction_id":21,"account_no":409000611074,"transaction_date":18490,"transaction_details":"INDO GIBL Indiaforensic STL13071 ","value_date":18490,"withdrawal_amt":"AV741A==","deposit_amt":null,"balance_amt":"KkPpRA=="},"source":{"version":"1.4.0-SNAPSHOT","connector":"mysql","name":"main.test.mysql","ts_ms":0,"snapshot":"true","db":"main","table":"test_bank_data","server_id":0,"gtid":null,"file":"binlog.000584","pos":15484438,"row":0,"thread":null,"query":null},"op":"c","ts_ms":1611582308774,"transaction":null}]|
#+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

You can modify your code to parse the `after` field in your json into a MapType then you select the keys you want as columns:

```
message_schema = StructType([
     StructField('before', MapType(StringType(), StringType(), True), True),
     StructField('after', MapType(StringType(), StringType(), True), True),
     StructField('source', MapType(StringType(), StringType(), True), True),
     StructField('op', StringType(), True),
     StructField('ts_ms', StringType(), True),
     StructField('transaction', StringType(), True)
     ]
)

after_fields = [
    "account_no", "balance_amt", "deposit_amt", "transaction_date",
    "transaction_details", "transaction_id", "value_date", "withdrawal_amt"
]

# parse json strings using from_json and select message.after.*
 kafkaStreamDF.withColumn(
     "message",
     F.from_json(F.col("value"), message_schema)
 ).select(
     *[F.col("message.after").getItem(f).alias(f) for f in after_fields]
 ).writeStream \
  .outputMode("append") \
  .format("console") \
  .option("truncate", "false") \
  .start() \
  .awaitTermination()
```

Comment: Hi @blacbishop Thanks for your reply.But when I am trying to use this logic I am getting error that -                                                                                                                                                               File "/home/ubuntu/python-scripts/pyspark-sql-test.py", line 24, in <module>
  json_message_rdd = kafkaStreamDF.select("value").limit(1).rdd.map(lambda row: row.value) pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();;kafka

Comment: @Nicolas Can you try with the updated answer?

Comment: @blackbishop looks like OP is just copy-pasting code, soyou may already add `awaitTermination` as well ;-)

Comment: @mike thank you for pointing it out. I'm not really using spark streaming but answered it as it's pure SQL transformations :)

Comment: @blackbishop : Thank you again for your reply.Now error is not comming but all rows data showing null null null for all columns and rows.I think something missing here with shema defination.I am reading the kafka message from Debezium connector with MySql database bin log.Message has many things but i taken the value of Payload part in kafkaStreamDF2 and from there I have given the output.I tried with you updated logic and i think schema of message still not in correct type for fileds and that is why coming null for fileds value.Please suggest .

Comment: @Nicolas the above code is based on the message format as it the table. What is the format of the message in the `value`  column?

Comment: @blackbishop : I have added the value which I am getting from Kafka message.Please check once and suggest.

Comment: @blackbishop : I have chcked the schema and tried some logic on debezium connector side to drop unwanted data from debezium connector and just to produce the after part of message into kafka.after then I tried with your provided logic and created new message_schema  as below and its working fine and showing the data as expacted in dataframe.Thank a lot for your help and suggestion :)